# Get difference between column strings in R dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, set-difference

I'm with a fundamental question in R:

Considering that I have a data frame, where each column represent the set of nucleotide mutations into two samples 'major' and 'minor'

```
major <- c("T2A,C26T,G652A")
minor <- c("T2A,C26T,G652A,C725T")

df <- data.frame(major,minor)
tibble(df)

#A tibble: 1 x 2
  major          minor               
  <chr>          <chr>               
1 T2A,C26T,G652A T2A,C26T,G652A,C725T
```

And I want to identify the mutations present in 'minor' that aren't in 'major'.

I know that if those 'major' and 'minor' mutations were stored vectors, I could use setdiff to get this difference, but, the data that I received is stored as a long string with some mutations separated by comma, and I don't know how transform this column string to a column vector in the data frame to get this difference (I tried without success).

using the setdiff directly in the columns:

```
setdiff(df$minor, df$major)
# I got
[1] "T2A C26T G652A C725T"
```

The expected results was:

```
C725T
```

Could anyone help me?

Best,

Comment: Each string is interpreted as a whole. If you want to treat the comma-separated substrings as individual elements, you need to split them into separate strings, e.g. using `strsplit`.

Comment: Your example is strange because you've created a 1-row data frame. There's not much point in having a data frame with only 1 row. In your real case do you have more rows? If so, do you need to compare the entire `minor` column to the entire `major` column, or is it a row-by-row comparison? Or is this single row data frame a good representation of your actual problem? The best solution will depend on those details.

Comment: I got the same

`df$major <- strsplit(df$major,',')
df$minor <- strsplit(df$minor,',')
tibble(df)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  major     minor    
  <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [3]> <chr [4]>

setdiff(df$minor, df$major)

[1] "T2A"   "C26T"  "G652A" "C725T"`

Comment: @GregorThomas Yeah, this is just a tiny example, In the real data frame I have several rows, but all rows in the same structure, a major and a minor column, to be compared row by row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on a multi-row data frame, doing comparisons by row:

```
library(dplyr)
major <- c("T2A,C26T,G652A", "world")
minor <- c("T2A,C26T,G652A,C725T", "hello,world")

df <- data.frame(major,minor)

df %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(major, minor), strsplit, split = ",")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = mapply(setdiff, minor, major)
  )
#              major                   minor  diff
# 1 T2A, C26T, G652A T2A, C26T, G652A, C725T C725T
# 2            world            hello, world hello
```

Note that it does modify the `major` and `minor` columns, turning them into list columns containing character vectors within each row. You can use the `.names` argument to `across` if you need to keep the originals.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, I will mark it as an accepted answer, this solution fixes my problem. Best,

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this; define `major` and `minor` as character vector

`major <- c("T2A", "C26T", "G652A")`

and

`minor <- c("T2A", "C26T", "G652A", "C725T")`

then

```
df <- tibble(major, minor)
setdiff(df$minor, df$major)
#> "C725T"
```

If not possible to split major and minor as character vector, you can use  `stringr` package to do that job.

```
library(stringr)

major <- c("T2A,C26T,G652A")
minor <- c("T2A,C26T,G652A,C725T")

df <- tibble(
  major = str_split(major, pattern = ",", simplify = TRUE), 
  minor = str_split(minor, pattern = ",", simplify = TRUE)
)

setdiff(df$minor, df$major)
#> "C725T"
```

Comment: thank @Angel F. Escalante for your answer.

I think that is useful, when I tried it in my environment I got `  unused argument (simplify = TRUE)`. 

But probably is something related to some library version.

Comment: Note that this will need some adjustment if `major` and `minor` are longer than 1. The `simplify = TRUE` will have to go, and `mapply` or similar will be needed to make `setdiff` work iteratively. (Though it looks great for the length-1 sample data OP posted!)